# grep \t matching letter "t", not tabs

Tags: unix, grep

I want to create a sequence of between n and m alphabetic characters, example 6 and 8, i.e. upper or lower case a through z. The sequence must be separated from the rest of the line by a space or tab character (on each side)

Why my code not working?!

```
grep -E [ \t][A-Za-z]{6,8}[ \t] myfile.dat
```

output gives all sequence of words between 6 and 8 and has space on each side, but for `\t` it translate it as letter t ?!!

what is wrong ?!

Comment: Quotes matter -- if you pass a string unquoted it's subject to string-splitting, glob expansion, brace expansion (meaning `{6,8}` is taken as an instruction to pass `grep` two separate arguments, one with a `6` in that location and another with an `8`), etc. Similarly, if you don't quote (and specifically, you need to use *single quotes* to make lone backslashes literal), backslashes are taken as instructions to the shell itself, not as content to pass unmodified to the (separate, not-a-part-of-the-shell-at-all) `grep` program.

Comment: (Similarly, there's no such thing as "bash grep"; grep isn't part of bash, it's provided by your operating system; you might have GNU grep, or Apple's grep, or FreeBSD grep, or... -- but whichever one it is, it'll behave identically no matter which shell you start it with, or if you invoke it without using any shell at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

This works for either tabs or spaces on both sides:

```
grep -E "[:space:][:alpha:]{6,8}[:space:]" myfile.dat
```

Also, as suggested by @CharlesDuffy in the comments, changing the `[A-Za-z]` to `[:alpha:]` will better handle non-standard locales.

Comment: I'd suggest `[:alpha:]` rather than `[A-Za-z]`, if you're going to be moving to character classes -- it'll behave more consistently in nonstandard locales that way (if your local language has letters after `z`, you probably don't want them excluded).

Answer (score 1):

By using $ sign in the beginning:

```
grep -E $'[ \t][A-Za-z]{6,8}[ \t]' myfile.dat
```

Comment: This is passing a literal tab character, not a `\t` sequence. It works (in ksh or bash -- baseline POSIX shells don't support this syntax at all, so it's not available everywhere), but it's certainly not the only solution: grep *does* allow `\t` sequences, if you prevent them from being munged by the shell before they reach it.